# How to send a binary message from Azure Function to Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-java-sdk, azure-java-tools

I used the following code to send some sample binary messages to a service bus from an Azure function, but on the service bus I always receive a message with the content `"System.Byte[]"` and the content type `"text/plain"`. I also tried to read the messages from the service bus with a Java app and I get the same result. When reading the messages with the Java app I expect to receive the specified array `new byte[] { 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`, not the byte array that represents the String `"System.Byte[]"`. I assume that the azure function sends the binary array as a String instead of byte array.

```
package azure.functions;

import com.microsoft.azure.functions.ExecutionContext;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.FunctionName;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.TimerTrigger;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.ServiceBusQueueOutput;

public class ServiceBusPeriodicSampleProducer {
    @FunctionName("ServiceBusPeriodicSampleProducer")
    @ServiceBusQueueOutput(
        name = "serviceBusBinaryMessage", 
        queueName = "test-queue", 
        connection = "ServiceBusConnection", 
        dataType = "binary"
    )
    public byte[] sendSampleMessageToServiceBus(
        @TimerTrigger(name = "timerInfo", schedule = "0 * * * * *") String timerInfo, final ExecutionContext context
    ) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java Timer trigger function executed at: " + java.time.LocalDateTime.now());
        return new byte[] { 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.servicebusqueueoutput?view=azure-java-stable), it looks like you need to add a parameter of type `OutputBinding<Byte[]>`, and set the value in that parameter using `outputBinding.SetValue(bytes)`, as opposed to having the bytes be returned from the method.

Comment: Thanks. I have already tried it and the result is the same.